# Cake PHP 2 custom Form->Label

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I'm using the Form helper to generate a label:

```
$this->Form->label('Contact.name', 'Name');
```

Which generates the following:

```
<label for="ContactName">Name</label>
```

Is it possible to generate the following using the helper:

```
<label for="ContactName"><span class="mandatory">*</span> Name</label>
```

Whilst I can manually write the html for the above it becomes a little more difficult when I am using the input method where a label is automatically generated.

For example:

```
$this->Form->input('Contact.forename',array('div' =>false,
                   'label' => array(
                   text'=> 'First Name',class =>'myclass'),
                   'class' => 'input','size' => '25' ,'tabindex' => '1'));
```

Is this possible in cake or do I have to manually inject the html using javascript when the page loads? Which I would think is rather ugly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using model validation for the mandatory fields then cakephp automatically applies '*' on the Label else you can use the helper as follows-

```
echo $this->Form->label('name', '<span class="mandatory">*</span> Name');
```

If you don't want the labels to generate automatically you can use "label => false" while using the helper.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Contact.forename',array('label' =>false));
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've ended up using both as I found my form validation errors only display when using form->input and don't when using form->text.  $this->Form->label('Contact.forename', '<span class="mandatory">*</span> Name'); and $this->Form->input('Contact.forename',array('div' =>false,'label' => false,'class' => 'input','size' => '25' ,'tabindex' => '2')); work great :-).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure CakePHP supports that (and it would get a bit messy anyway). The simplest solution I can think of is to assign a "mandatory" class to the label via the form helper:

```
$this->Form->label('User.name', 'Your username', array('class'=>'mandatory'));
```

Which produces something like:

```
<label class="mandatory" for="ContactName">Name</label>
```

Then the rest is done purely in CSS:

```
label.mandatory:after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
    display: inline;
}
```

Avoids having any additional HTML.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, not thought to do it this way. The only downside I see is that I have to create several classes for the different content. Consider If I wanted (if applicable) as the content.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but maybe someone with Cakephp 3 is having the same problem. This is what fixed it for me, without any inlinecode.

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input(
'renovate_old',
[
 'type' => 'checkbox',
 'label' => ['text' => __('Alte Wohnung'), 'class' => 'moCheckLabel']
]); ?>
```

So you can name your label and use the Databasefield to write.

Comment: It also works with CakePHP 1.3.x 

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simple by

```
echo $this->Form->input('whatever', array('between'=>'<label for="ContactName"><span class="mandatory">*</span> Name</label>','label'=>false));
```